# Why the DropDownButtonFormField does not need a setState to to rebuild, while the DropDownButton needs it?

Tags: flutter, dropdownbutton

I tried to figure it out, and read the documentation for both but I didn't find an answer, here is an example of what I mean:

```
List<String> items = ["item1", "item2", "item3", "item4"];
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  HomeScreen({super.key});
  String selectedItem = items[0];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            child: DropdownButton(
              value: selectedItem,
              onChanged: (value) => selectedItem = value!,
              items: items
                  .map(
                    (e) => DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                      value: e,
                      child: Text(e),
                    ),
                  )
                  .toList(),
            ),
...
```

that's just a simple stateless widget with a **DropdownButton** at the center:
[output of the code above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fb4kk.gif)

if we just change the widget to a **DropdownButtonFormField** with all else remain the same, changes to the selected item reflect in the UI: [output of the same code after changing the widget to a **DropdownButtonFormField**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rc7Kg.gif)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dig inside `DropdownButtonFormField` you will see it keeps a separate value for the menu inside its state. If you explore the code it says

```
onChanged: onChanged == null ? null : state.didChange,
```

`state.didChange` looks like:

```
  @override
  void didChange(T? value) {
    super.didChange(value);
    final DropdownButtonFormField<T> dropdownButtonFormField = widget as DropdownButtonFormField<T>;
    assert(dropdownButtonFormField.onChanged != null);
    dropdownButtonFormField.onChanged!(value);
  }
```

and `super.didChange` looks like

```
  void didChange(T? value) {
    setState(() {
      _value = value;
      _hasInteractedByUser.value = true;
    });
    Form.of(context)?._fieldDidChange();
  }
```

This changes the iternal value of the state and calls `setState` so that it refreshes the UI for it.

As a result, even if you change this line of your code:

```
onChanged: (value) => selectedItem = value!,
```

to

```
onChanged: (value){},
```

It still works visually, because it doesn't actually use `selectedItem` but the internal value.